# Application Registration

Tags: authentication

I am creating an application and I want to have the application 'authenticate' with some form of registration key in order to cut down on piracy. I was thinking of perhaps building a string when the customer purchases the product and use something like MD5 to create a hash.

The question I have is where is the best place to store this key once it's entered.I am also curious how you design the application to require it or not allow it to run.

EDIT:
The application is written in .NET and any server side techonlogy that will be used will interface with SQL Server database.

Comment: It would help to know what server side technology you are using -php, asp.net, rails etc.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts... is this a 'one time activation', or something that happens each time the app runs? Users tend to view the latter as a privacy concern. I've gone down the path of one-time registration, with an app called Protection Plus. It handles generation of the challenge/response, which is really the hard part.

PP creates a challenge key which changes each time the form is loaded on the client. With this key, the remote system generates a 'trigger code' using the challenge and a system code provided by the client. PP can be configured to create this system code in several different ways... a bios hash, hard drive serial #, hard drive volume label, etc, ...

When the trigger code is created (which does one of several actions), and sent back to the client, PP decrypts it and returns the correct integer-based action to take.

If interested, check it out:
[Protection Plus Website](http://www.softwarekey.com/protection-plus/)

Comment: One time activation is what I was thinking. I don't want a customer to have to be online everytime they use the application to make sure their key is valid.

Comment: Ok, if you're going to roll your own.. the challenge ideally should key composed of (1) data that changes each time, and (2) a machine-specific piece of data. You save those in the registry or app.config. Those would be sent to the server, which then issue a code using those two things, which the client would then verify. You could then stash the response in the registry or app.config so that it auto verifies on each start.